# Probability distribution of binary multiplier channel

Tags: information-theory

The *binary multiplier channel* is described in Section 15.3.2 of Cover and Thomas (second edition), as follows:

> Consider a multiple access channel with binary inputs and output $Y=X_1X_2$. Such channel is called a binary multiplier channel. It is easy to see that by setting $X_2=1$, we can send at a rate of 1 bit per transmission from sender 1 to the receiver. Similarly, setting $X_1=1$, we can achieve $R_2=1$. Clearly, since the output is binary, the combined rates $R_1 + R_2$ of sender 1 and sender 2 cannot be more than 1 bit. By timesharing, we can achieve any combination of rates such that $R_1 + R_2=1$.

What is the probability distribution $P(X_1, X_2, Y)$ for a equal time share?

| $X_1$ | $X_2$ | $Y$ | P(X_1,X_2,Y) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | ? |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | ? |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | ? |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | ? |

Comment: This doesn't make any sense on the face of it, because a probability distribution assigns *probabilities,* not logical values, to the empty cells in the table, but a truth table assigns logical values.  Please explain.

Comment: Hey Whuber, I was missing you! I use your $I(X)$ as one of the most bizarre information theory error, when I explain these information quantities in classes. Sometime the term truth table is also used for the probability tables.

Comment: Re the edits: unfortunately, you haven't supplied any probability information one could use to formulate an answer.  The column for $Y$ is superfluous, because $Y=X_1X_2.$ What you need, then, is to supply probability distributions for the $X_i$ along with one more quantitative piece of information about their dependence.  In English, "truth table" has a well established meaning that differs from anything about probabilities, so although I don't question your assertion, I suspect there might have been a translation error.

Comment: Wuhber, why don't you just let your colleagues try answering the question? You also write stuff like that there is no correspondence between information theory and set theory despite the tons of articles and books on the subject, that there is a mutual information for one variable and is identically zero etc. Just let the people from the field address it. You might be surprised...

Comment: Have I done anything to stop anyone from answering this question?  I know you object to moderation.  The solution for you is to post on unmoderated sites.  But as long as you continue to post here, we will ask you to abide by our standards and rules.  That's not going to change.

Comment: OK. You are right. Let's start a post discussion on meta on some of your comments on information theory stuff and about the quality of these rules. I think it is a good idea. Maybe it is the rules that need some fixing. Should a person who write "what's the information I(X) for a random variable X that is almost surely a constant?" be allowed to moderate posts on information theory? Or what about "Set theory has nothing at all to do with information theoretic quantities." when you just need to open Yeung's book (or the latest development on shared information) to learn a lot about it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134380/discussion-between-cesare-and-whuber).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear whether you want $X_1$ and $X_2$ to be dependent or independent.  If they are dependent, you can define a multinomial distribution such that $\mbox{Pr}(X_1=0,X_2=0)=p_1$, $\mbox{Pr}(X_1=0,X_2=1)=p_2$, and $\mbox{Pr}(X_1=1,X_2=0)=p_3$.  Then, $\mbox{Pr}(X_1=1,X_2=1)=1-p_1-p_2-p_3$.  However, I will assume that you mean that these variables are independent.

Let $X_1 \sim Bernoulli(p_{x_1})$ and $X_2 \sim Bernoulli(p_{x_2})$.  Additionally let $Y=X_1 X_2$.  I imagine that you want to find the joint distribution of $(X_1,X_2,Y)$ in order to evaluate the conditional mutual information $I(X_2;Y|X_1)$ using the result that
\begin{eqnarray*}
I(X_2;Y|X_1) = I(X_1,X_2;Y)-I(X_1;Y),
\end{eqnarray*}
where the mutual informations (not Fisher's information matrix) are defined as
\begin{eqnarray*}
I(X_1;Y) &=& \sum_{x_1=0}^1 \sum_{y=0}^1 \mbox{Pr}(X_1=x_1,Y=y) \ln \left[\frac{\mbox{Pr}(X_1=x_1,Y=y) }{\mbox{Pr}(X_1=x_1) \mbox{Pr}(Y=y) }\right] \\
I(X_1,X_2;Y) &=& \sum_{x_1=0}^1 \sum_{x_2=0}^1 \sum_{y=0}^1 \mbox{Pr}(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,Y=y) \ln \left[\frac{\mbox{Pr}(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,Y=y) }{\mbox{Pr}(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2) \mbox{Pr}(Y=y) }\right].
\end{eqnarray*}

In order to evaluate either $\mbox{Pr}(X_1=x_1,Y=y)$ or $\mbox{Pr}(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,Y=y)$, one should express the intersection of events as the product of a conditional and marginal probability.  Specifically,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mbox{Pr}(X_1=x_1,Y=y) &=& \mbox{Pr}(Y=y|X_1=x_1) \mbox{Pr}(X_1=x_1) \\
\mbox{Pr}(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,Y=y) &=& \mbox{Pr}(Y=y|X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2) \mbox{Pr}(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2).
\end{eqnarray*}

For instance,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mbox{Pr}(X_1=1,Y=1) &=& \mbox{Pr}(Y=1|X_1=1) \mbox{Pr}(X_1=1) \\
&=& \mbox{Pr}(X_2=1) \mbox{Pr}(X_1=1) \\
&=& p_{x_1} p_{x_2},
\end{eqnarray*}
where the second line follows since if $X_1=1$ then $Y=1$ only when $X_2=1$.  Likewise,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mbox{Pr}(X_1=0,Y=1) &=& \mbox{Pr}(Y=1|X_1=0) \mbox{Pr}(X_1=0) \\
&=& 0,
\end{eqnarray*}
since if $X_1=0$ then $Y=1$ with probability 0 (i.e. it must be equal to 0).

Using this technique one can enumerate the 8 exhaustive events which define the joint density of $(X_1, X_2, Y)$.  For instance,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mbox{Pr}(X_1=0,X_2=0,Y=0) &=& \mbox{Pr}(Y=0|X_1=0,X_2=0) \mbox{Pr}(X_1=0,X_2=0) \\
&=& \mbox{Pr}(X_1=0,X_2=0) \\
&=& (1-p_{x_1}) (1-p_{x_2})
\end{eqnarray*}
since conditional on the event that $X_1=0$ and $X_2=0$, $Y=0$ with probability 1.  Likewise,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mbox{Pr}(X_1=0,X_2=0,Y=1) &=& \mbox{Pr}(Y=1|X_1=0,X_2=0) \mbox{Pr}(X_1=0,X_2=0) \\
&=& 0
\end{eqnarray*}
since $\mbox{Pr}(Y=1|X_1=0,X_2=0) = 1-\mbox{Pr}(Y=0|X_1=0,X_2=0) =0.$

Note, these terms with zero probability (there will be 4), are treated as zeroes in $I(X_1,X_2;Y)$.  Hence, one may re-write this equation as
\begin{eqnarray*}
I(X_1,X_2;Y) &=& \sum_{x_1=0}^1 \sum_{x_2=0}^1  \mbox{Pr}(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,Y=x_1 x_2) \ln \left[\frac{\mbox{Pr}(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,Y=x_1 x_2) }{\mbox{Pr}(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2) \mbox{Pr}(Y=x_1 x_2) }\right].
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will go through it carefully. Indeed I think that one should consider $X_1$ and $X_2$ independently. What I am trying to do is compute the partial information decomposition for this distribution, but to do that I need the probability distribution to begin with, and I got stuck there.

Comment: @Cesare Note that $Y|X_1,X_2$ in the example takes a single value with probability one.  This is called a degenerate distribution and its entropy function $H(Y|X_1,X_2)$ is zero, as expected.  One could have also used $X_1,X_2 | Y$ and the marginal distribution of $Y$ to construct the probabilities, but these appear more difficult to evaluate, though still being straightforward.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. $X_1$ and $X_2$ must be dependent in order to implement the scheme in which $X_1 = 1$ and $X_2$ can communicate or vice-versa (with a chosen time sharing). Essentially $Pr(X1=0,X2=0)$ is forced to zero. How can one proceed in this case?

Comment: I think I have it. It is $P(X_1=0, X_2=1) = P(X_1=1, X_2=0) = P(X_1=1, X_2=1) = 1/3$ (for the equal time use of the channel).